# Postgres. DDL which are not rollback in transaction

Tags: postgresql

Please, tell me, how to find the full list of DDL, which are not rollback in transaction? I find thsese ddl commands.

```
cluster
commit prepared
create database
create tablespace
discard
drop database
drop tablespace
rollback prepared
vacuum
REINDEX DATABASE
REINDEX SYSTEM

Nextval and Setval operations on sequences are never rolled back.
```